# Why Won't Python Won't Do a Lot of Recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I'm doing the Project Euler problems, and I'm on number two. The question is:

***Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.***

I'm trying to solve this in python. I think I have the correct code, but for some reason When I run it with n being anything greater than or equal to 27, it will wait like a minute and just return 0. However, for anything 26 or lower, it runs fine. Here's my code:

```
def fib_seq(n):
    if n == 0:
        return n
    elif n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib_seq(n-1) + fib_seq(n-2)

def get_fib_sum(n):
    x = n
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if fib_seq(x) > 4000000:
            pass
        elif fib_seq(x) % 2 == 0:
            pass
        else:
            sum += fib_seq(x)
            x = i
    return sum

print get_fib_sum(27)
```

Is there anyway to fix this or at least get it to work? If it makes a difference, I'm using Wing IDE 101 Student Edition.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `fib_seq(i)`, not `fib_seq(x)`?

Comment: @Kevin existing answers are comments and your comment is the answer.

Comment: Another tip: `sum()` is a builtin function in python. You shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name, since it can cause confusing bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop, you are using `fib_seq(x)` and it should be `fib_seq(i)`

Also, if you want to reduce time a bit more, you can use memoization technique

```
def fib_seq(n):
    if n == 0:
        return n
    elif n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib_seq(n-1) + fib_seq(n-2)

def memoize(fn, arg):
 memo = {}
 if arg not in memo:
  memo[arg] = fn(arg)
  return memo[arg]


fibm = memoize(fib_seq,27)
print fibm
```

Comment: Use the `functools.lru_cache` decorator instead of implementing it yourself.

Comment: I tried to run the original code to see why it's slow.
get_fib_sum(27) will call fib_seq() more than 34 million times.

Comment: @HåkenLid  I update my answer, you should use `fib_seq(i)` not `fib_seq(x) `in your loop

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using recursion? your code is recalculating the **ENTIRE** fibonnaci sequence over and over and over and over and over... The code just wants the sum of the even terms. There is **NO** need for recursion. In pseudo-code:

```
t1 = 1
t2 = 2;
sum = 2;
do {
   t3 = t1 + t2;
   if (t3 is even) {
      sum += t3;
   }
   t1 = t2;
   t2 = t3;
} while (t2 <= 4000000)
```

Answer (score 3):

Fibonacci sequence is often used as an example of how to write recursive code, which is ridiculous because it has a very straight-forward iterative solution:

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        a, b = 1, 1
        for _ in range(2, n):    # O(n)
            a, b = b, a+b
        return b
```

What is less obvious is that it also has a matrix representation,

```
F = [[0, 1]]      # initial state

T = [[0, 1],      # transition matrix
     [1, 1]]

fib(n) = (F * T**n)[0][0]
```

which is extremely useful because `T**n` can be computed in `O(log(n))` steps.

(As an aside, the eigenvector of the log of the transition matrix leads to the analytic solution,

```
phi = (1 + 5**0.5) / 2     # golden ratio
fib(n) = round(phi**n / 5**0.5, 0)
```

but that's not where I'm going with this.)

Looking at the terms produced in terms of odd-or-even, you see

```
n:        0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8, ... 
f(n):     0,    1,    1,    2,    3,    5,    8,   13,   21, ...
e/o:   even,  odd,  odd, even,  odd,  odd, even,  odd,  odd, ...
```

so what you need is `fib(0) + fib(3) + fib(6) + ...` and computing `T**3` gives you the coefficients needed to step directly from term to term.

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It does a lot of recursion, that's why it's taking so long.

The `get_fib_sum()` will evaluate `fib_seq(27)` in a loop, which does a lot of recursion and takes a while. Since the result of `fib_seq(27)` is greater then 4000000 it will then will never add anything to `sum`, returning 0 in the end.